# Visual Studio 2022 - Compiler Error CS1900 : Warning level must be in the range 0-4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, warning-level

**project.csproj file**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <NoWarn>;NU1701</NoWarn>
    <WarningLevel>5</WarningLevel>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <WarningsAsErrors>;NU1605</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <NoWarn>;NU1701</NoWarn>
    <WarningLevel>5</WarningLevel>
    <WarningsAsErrors>;NU1605</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I did set WarningLevel to 5 - Warning from C#9  and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1900?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1900)
was not expecting any compiler error

Comment: Works on my machine, VS2022 version 17.7.4.  Consider updating VS, perhaps.

Comment: What is the `<LangVersion>` you are using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 17.8.2, I tried following the tutorial in the link and this works. If your steps are correct, try updating Visual Studio